# WCF Cyclic Reference and can not solve with IsReference = true

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, cyclic-reference

I know that this question have asked a million times. But my case, I weird and I don't understand.
I got a cyclic reference and below are my code/configuration:

1. I have Entity as a base class for all entities.

   ```
   [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
   public class Entity : IEntity
   ```
2. Inherited class is like this, and created by Entity Framework 6

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public partial class User: Entity
   ```

   I have `Group`, `User`, `GroupUser`, `GroupAdministrator`. The name here is clear, I think. `Group` has `GroupUser`, `User` has `GroupUser` and `GroupUser` has `Group & User`.
3. In DbContext, proxy creation is turned off, lazy loading is on.
4. **Error comes from this method, when I call it, I got a** `cyclic reference`.

   ```
   public IList<Group> GetGroups()
   {
       return _groupRepository.GetAll(true, _ => _.GroupAdministrators.Select(__=>__.User), _ => _.GroupUsers.Select(__ => __.User));
   }
   ```

   I debug and the root cause is this: `_ => _.GroupUsers.Select(__ => __.User)`

   The `_groupRepository.GetAll()`:

   ```
   public IList<T> GetAll(bool? isActive = true, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
   {
       IQueryable<T> query = BrokerageSimulatorContext.Set<T>()
           .Where(_ => (isActive.HasValue && _.IsActive == isActive) || !isActive.HasValue);
       return includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty)).ToList();
   }
   ```
5. Why I need ? `_ => _.GroupUsers.Select(__ => __.User)` Because I need to include the Users of that group when list all groups.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to look at the data before you return it? _Is_ there a cyclical reference?

Comment: Yes, there is no cyclic reference because the proxy create is turn off=> groupUser object has no group object, and groupUser.User object has no group....